# How to get rid of many lines with different string in linux shell

Tags: shell, grep

In my linux shell, I want to get rid  of specific line.

I use grep -v like:

```
 ps -aux | grep -v root | grep -v gdm | grep -v sshd | grep -v zabbix | grep -v bash    | grep -v ssh | grep -v usr
```

So I use too much grep -v, it is ugly.

I had tried:

```
ps -axu | grep -v "root && gdm && sshd && zabbix && bash && ssh && usr"
```

But it failed. I had tried another way:

```
ps -axu | grep -v root && gdm && sshd && zabbix && bash && ssh && usr;
```

Unlucky, it failed again.

I think sed or awk may solve this problem, but I don't know how

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to use pipe in a string which you need to escape.  You need to do it the following way:

```
ps -axu | grep -v "root\|gdm\|sshd\|zabbix\|bash\|ssh\|usr"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -axu | grep -Ev 'root|gdm|ssh|zabbix|bash|usr'
```

Of course this would also exclude a process named, say, *groot* or *usrmgr*, but this problem is present in your original solution too.

Note that at least with more recent versions of gnu grep, the -E switch is not needed anymore, because Gnu grep always interprets the regexp as extended regular expression. Specifying -E guarantees that the command will work even if you have "traditional" (non-Gnu) grep in your path.